# Laravel Property [nameOfProperty] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: relationship, is-empty, laravel-5.7

I am fetching a user in Laravel along with it's relation; competitionResults.

`$user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('competitionResults')->get();`

I now want to check if competitionResults is empty, because it is returning this error: **Property [competitionsResults] does not exist on this collection instance.**

I've tried

`if ($user->competitionResults()->exists()) {...}`

`if ($user->competitionResults()->isNotEmpty()) {...}`

`if (count($user->competitionResults)) {...}`

But they all return the same error.

How does one check wether the relation data is empty?

[image: dd of user]

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if the property exists on the *collection*, rather than the Model. Use `first()` instead of `get()` to return an instance of the User class.

Comment: Thomas is correct you are using `get()` on user model which returns you an array of users